# Make 3.82 - Backward incompatibility issue?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm having some issues after try to run some small Makefile with make 3.82.

error:

```
[me@localhost make]$ make
 Makefile:3: *** empty variable name.  Stop.
```

This works with make 3.81, but not with the new one. I know there are some backward compatibilities with the old version.

I have two Makefiles, a base one and main one.

This is my Makebase

```
define TestFile
ifeq ($$(shell test $(1) $(2) || echo 1),1)
    $$(error $(2) mmm, not found)
endif
endef

define CheckIt
$(eval $(call TestFile,-d,$(1)))
endef

define CheckDir
p := $(foreach d,$1,$(call CheckIt,$d))
endef


define SomeCheck
$(call CheckDir,$(1))
endef
```

This is my Makefile

```
include Makebase

$(call SomeCheck, ~/test/make)
```

As I said, it works fine in make 3.81.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

BR

Comment: Are you sure that works the way you think it does for 3.81? Here is looks like that sets `p` as a target with `=` as a prerequisite. (You aren't using `eval` on the result of calling `SomeCheck`. Adding `eval` also makes 3.82 work on the makefile for whatever definition of work I can call this mess.) This seems like a fairly horrible way to do things (you are forcibly shelling out repeatedly *during* make parse time, that's going to be costly). What's the goal with all of this?

Comment: Hi Etan, this is an extract of the Big mess I'm dealing with , not done by me. The thing is, after updating to make 3.82 there are a lot of empty variable names errors, and this what just a proof of concept of that issue. Looks like the eval do the work, but not sure why eval do the different in 3.82? thanks a lot

Comment: Now then think is, should the eval warp the calling of SomeChek or it can be done in the definition of SomeCheck? Thanks

Comment: Honestly, I would suggest either not upgrading make at all or throwing out whatever make system this is that does things like this and starting again from scratch. Because I don't believe the above works correctly at all and is a really poor design as well.

Comment: I'm totally agreed with you, but for now dropping out the system is not an option. Keeping 3.81 is not an option either. Will see... Thanks Etan.

Comment: Porting to a new version of make is not a simple operation. You need to be sure that you **exactly** understand what the build system is doing to be sure that you replicate that after the port or you could lose crucial dependency information and/or introduce new unnecessary dependencies. If you believe this works correctly with make 3.81 (and I would suggest you **very carefully** check that assumption because I'm not at all sure it is true) then you should dump the entire make database (`-p`) and a verbose build of the project (`-d` even maybe) using make 3.81 to compare against later.

Answer (score 1):

So, I have no idea what this was intended to do in GNU make 3.81.  As Etan points out, when I run your makefile with GNU make 3.81 I get this error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `=', needed by `p'.  Stop.
```

That's because a `call` function cannot expand to a variable assignment, so make interprets the `p :=` as if it were `p: =` (that is, a target `p` with a prerequisite of `=`).  I don't see how this is actually what you want.  If you don't see this error all I can assume is that somewhere in your makefile, someone has declared a recipe with target `=` (ugh!!)

In GNU make 3.82 I see the `empty variable name` message.  The reason for this is that GNU make 3.82 introduced parser enhancements which caused some backwards-incompatibility.  The NEWS file gives this warning:

> As a result of parser enhancements, three backward-compatibility issues
>     exist: first, a prerequisite containing an "=" cannot be escaped with a
>     backslash any longer.  You must create a variable containing an "=" and
>     use that variable in the prerequisite.

An unnoticed side-effect of this is that an equals sign with no value before it in the prerequisites list is now considered a target-specific variable where the variable name is empty, whereas before it was assumed to be a target since it didn't meet the requirements for a variable assignment.  I am not sure this is a bug... in general I'm not a fan of "tricking" the parser with odd corner cases so I actually prefer the newer behavior.

This entire define is quite bogus:

```
define CheckDir
p := $(foreach d,$1,$(call CheckIt,$d))
endef
```

Why?  Because the `CheckIt` user-defined function contains nothing but an `eval` statement.  But `eval` statements are expanded and the results parsed by make, so they *always* expand to the empty string.  Therefore, the entire `foreach` loop expands to the empty string.  Therefore even if this were interpreted as you (apparently) intended by make, it would always simply expand to:

```
p :=
```

which doesn't seem very useful.  If you change the above define to simply:

```
define CheckDir
$(foreach d,$1,$(call CheckIt,$d))
endef
```

then it will always work, and you won't see these weird problems.

I'm not going to comment on how bogus this makefile is in general... :)